# How to safe store password in database?

Tags: php, node.js, security, encryption

I wonder about creation password storage tool for my company, based on PHP or NodeJS. Currently we keep passwords in KeePass but it's not good for sharing password between employees.

We need to keep passwords, not hash. I just looking for good practices how to store passwords in safe way. How to encrypt password? Are there any open tools to encrypt passwords?

Comment: Why do you need to be able to access your plain text passwords in the first place?

Comment: Do you mean passwords that need to be shared between employees? Or are these passwords in a user table (in which case you don't need access to the plaintext version at all)?

Comment: `How to encrypt password?`  Too broad a question, covered ad nauseam on Stack Overflow and searchable on Google.  `Are there any open tools to encrypt passwords?`  Tool recommendations are off-topic for Stack Overflow as well.

Comment: If you're looking to share passwords, try https://pwdshare.com/ or https://www.passpack.com/. I've no experience of either (found these with a trivial search).

Comment: should employees really be shareing the passwords at all?

Comment: @leneya some times people (sys. admins. for example) have a long list of password because they 'manage' many different softwares\system and they just can't remember all those 12 character long auto generated passwords. I guess that would be a good reason and why OP needs it. Actually there are many solutions that do exactly what he, probably, wants to "reinvent".

Comment: @JhulianoMoreno makes sense. Just wanted more context, because I've been a part of a few systems that had unencrypted passwords for situations that didn't call for it. (IE to spoof a user they would store unencrypted passwords and login using other user's credentials, instead of creating a user spoofing system). Just wanted to make sure that wasn't the case here, as that is major insecure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this right is not for the newbie/faint of heart.

In order for the system to be secure then the passwords should be held in a form which is not readable by anyone without access. Storing the (complete) access method in the application means the data is not secure. Hence the passwords need to be stored with some sort of reversible encryption but the key must not be stored on the server.

Unfortunately you need to know the key in order to put encrypted data into the database. With symmetric encryption (same key for encryption and decryption) that's not too much of a problem if everyone gets access to all the passwords - but that is *very* limited in its value and in most cases would undermine security.

The solution is, when setting or updating a password, to encrypt it with an asymmetric cipher using the public key of each user whom should have access - resulting in multiple copies of the encrypted password each of which can only be decrypted using the private key of the user.

Hence each password would be represented by a series of records, one for each user, containing the relevant user identity, the encrypted password, an initialization vector, and the target account for the password. You would also need to retain public keys for each user, and provide a mechanism for them to bring the encrypted data and their private key together - sending the data out in an email would one solution. Allowing a user to upload their private key is not a good idea. You might store the private key on local storage on a browser and decrypt in Javascript.